# Fractional powers of the Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory, fractional-calculus

I have recently started to study fractional fractional powers of the Laplacian. In the books I've read, fractional powers are defined only for
$$-\Delta =-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j^2}.$$
My question is: why are fractional powers set to $-\Delta$ and not to $\Delta$? Is this somehow related to the spectrum of $-\Delta$ being positive?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Partial answer is: due to well known  representation of $-(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ and applications see: Mateusz Kwaśnicki article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.07356.pdf I don't know much about the Fractional powers of the $\Delta$ so I will leave it as that (hopefully the article will help a little ).

Comment: The main point is that $-\Delta$ is a positive definite operator on $C^2$ functions, unlike $\Delta.$